# How do I fetch and display data from various website APIs?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and C++. I would also like to learn how to get data from websites like Google (Analytics, Gmail, Plans, etc.) Facebook, Twitter, etc., and display it on my website.

For instance: I'd like to be able to access, from Google Analytics, how many people visited my website, their locations, OS, etc., then display it on my website.

Or to be able to post comments or delete them on my Business Facebook Page directly from my personal webpage. Or at least see if there's new activity on Facebook directly from my personal website.

I tried to understand oAuth and Google APIs through Google's tutorials, but the information on their pages are just as messy and scattered as their Android's guides.

I don't even know what languages I should learn to do something like this. I don't know what to search for in the net.

Is there a term for this kind of process? Is this the same as Data Mining? I tried to search Google, but couldn't find anything that could help me, as a beginner.

Is there a book for beginners, with clear information? Perhaps a youtube Channel with tutorials? Where do I begin here?

**EDIT:**

Maybe they are not language dependent, but there should be a way to learn how to implement them using a language like Java, for example. This is  what I cannot find.

And yes, I am asking for functionalities found in websites’ APIs, and each one is different, but they must make some sense, because if people can make it work, it’s because they’d learn it somehow. I guess I am asking how to learn to make sense of these APIs.

I do not know where to start, because the tutorials on Facebook, Google, etc., they all seem to assume some kind of previous knowledge. Google searches has been proving unfruitful as well.

I’m not asking for a step-by-step; this would be ludicrous, given the complexity of the issue. What I am asking, however, is for guided directions. I don’t know what to study, I don’t know the name of the process so I can search for it more effectively, I can’t seem to find any books about it, nothing.

Comment: as is, this question is a little broad. Several of the things you mention do exist, but overall the question is so broad that it seems like answers would be mostly opinion based. I recommend making sure you have a solid grounding in basic programming, then doing some more research. For example, Facebook has an API that you can use directly, or there are third-party APIs that wrap it to try and make it simpler to use, such as Spring Social. Then come back to Stack Overflow when you get stuck, and have specific issues using specific technologies.

Comment: Search for "Java consume API" or "Java curl JSON", that will get you plenty of results.

Comment: @halfer thank you, halfer

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer a few of your distinct questions:

> The problem is, I don't even know what languages I should learn to do something like this. I don't know what to search for in the net.

This isn't very language dependent. Most general-purpose, mainstream languages should be equivalent. Even with a less-used language, you can still use APIs via HTTP requests, etc., that are not language dependent.

> Is there a term for this kind of process? Is this the same as Data Mining?

Yes, this is a thing. No, it is not quite data mining. You're asking for functionality that exists in website APIs. Facebook has one, so do the other social networks, and so does Google analytics. Each one is different, so you should look for answers by searching things like "how to get [x] using [some website] API".

> Is there a book for beginners, with clear information? Perhaps a youtube Channel with tutorials? Where do I begin here?

As mentioned above, do this on a website-by-website basis, because you **will** need separate, different code for each website. There will be some similarities, but each API will require different methods of authentication, will have different functionality available, and will return different types of data. You could try starting with [Facebook's API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/) which is fairly complete, and therefore might cause less frustration. I'm sure a google search will return tutorials on using it for various things.

Comment: ...Well, don't go saying that the OP's question is a little broad and then *proceed to answer it*...that sends an *incredibly* mixed message.